# CSS styles not being applied prior to form submit on iPad/iPhone

Tags: asp.net, webforms

We have deployed a new design to our web site and have a problem with some styling that is not being applied but only on iPad mini, and iPhone 6 (actually it seems to work on some versions if both but this testing is done using BrowserStack).

There is the code:
        $(".form-btn").bind("click", function () {
            SubmitForm();
        });

```
    SubmitForm = function () {
        $('.error').hide();
        $('.form-search').addClass('show');
        $('#mainContent_subButton').click();
    }
```

If I remove the button click, the styles are applied.  The styling being applied is 1.) showing an animated loader gif, 2.) disabling button and textboxes;

This is an ASP.Net WebForms site.

Comment: I suppose the browser interrupts the rendering after the click, so it's too fast to see.

Comment: This site does numerous retailer searches and the postback usually takes at least 3 or 4 seconds before the page is redirected (if there are results).  This is only an issue on the Apple products and have same results in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: So you want a "wait for it" animation while the postback is doing it's thing?

Comment: @Alexander - you are correct - the styles are being applied (although the gif does not animate) http://prntscr.com/ailplt

Comment: As you say, without the PostBack, it works. I assume the browser stops caring about the CSS changes once the PostBack has started.